# Splash video everytime a user visits the webpage?

Tags: php, cookies

I have created a splash-video which is played when a visitor visits the page for the first time. With a cookie I can set an expiration time when this splash-video will popup again. What I'd like to achive instead is when this splash-video is played on first visit it will only display again on next visit (when user closes the tab or closes the web browser window).

What I have read while searching, if I don't set an cookie expiration this should work.

```
setcookie( 'my_cookie', 1 );
```

The problem is that if user in for example Chrome have settings set to "On Start -> Continue where you left off", this behaviuor won't work.

Is there really a bullet-proof way of achieving what I want?

Kind regards
Johan

UPDATE:

This seems to work fine. Any comments on that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (/(^|;)\s*bvssp_visited=/.test(document.cookie)) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "welcome back";
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){document.cookie = "bvssp_visited=true; max-age=" + 10 * 1},1000);
} else {
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){document.cookie = "bvssp_visited=true; max-age=" + 10 * 1},1000);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hi new user";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you consider using sessions? If the session ends, the user will get the splash video again.

Comment: Yes, but I assume a session still needs to be set in time? When session-time is up splash-video will display again? Then I can set cookie time like I have done before? Or is there a way to use session without time limit? Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: As long as a user is browsing your website and clicks links etcetera, a session will not timeout. However, if the user doesn't do anything any more a session does time out (for example when the user isn't actually there any more). You can almost always rely that a user isn't there any more when their session times out.

Comment: I get it. Also Google doesn't clear session cookies and sees it like an feature. Lame if you ask me. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/cjt3WwgOJ3c

What I understand there is no solution to my problem. Only stick with cookie time or an session-time? :)

Comment: Yeah it can be a bit annoying at times.

Comment: Check my updated post @Boy and veryone else ofc :)

Comment: No comments on this, seems like a good idea.